# Supply mission to ISS

Tags: soyuz-spacecraft

Since the blowing up of third stage of Soyuz 2.1a it has been put at back burner and older version of Soyuz -TM put into survice. My question is since the contract with ESA also expire in 2016 when will we see it on active duty?  When it will cleared safe for human again?